# Why is my custom model not showing up on scanning NFT using AR.JS?

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

I have already tried debugging it and the NFT is being detected. The box is loading when the NFT is scanned but my custom model/asset #avocado is not showing up. The model appears to be moving around with the NFT but you just can't see it.

```
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="avocado" src="%BASE_URL%assets/models/Avocado.glb"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>

      <a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="%BASE_URL%assets/nfts/pattern-qr-code"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5"
      >
        <a-entity scale="100 100 100">
          <a-entity
            position="0 0 0"
            gltf-model="#avocado"
            scale="20 20 20"
            rotation="-45 90 0"
            id="avocado-entity"
          ></a-entity>
          <a-box position="0 0.25 0" material="opacity: 0.5;" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-box>
        </a-entity>
      </a-nft>
      <a-entity camera id="camera"></a-entity>
```

I have already checked and the paths are right. All scripts are already imported and nothing seems wrong on that side. Have tried changing the size, angles etc already but still no results.